# Show that the matrix $A$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Let

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\
    2 & 5 & 4 & -5\\
    3 & 4 & 14 & -2 \\
    -2 & -5 & -2 & 10 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Show that the matrix $A$ is positive definite (that is $x^T A x >0$ for each $x \neq 0$)

I have noticed that $A$ is a symmetric matrix and hence it induces a quadratic form $q_A(x)=x^T A x$. I also know that a quadratic form $q_A$ is positive definite (which is $x^T A x >0$ for each $x \neq 0$) if and only if all the eigen values of $A$ are positive, but ¿Is there an easier way to solve the problem, sice it is a $4 \times 4$ matrix and it will take some time to compute $det(A-\lambda I)$? and It also might be hard to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$

Comment: You can reduce $A$ to a diagonal matrix $D$ by apply a series of row operations and applying the same operations to the columns.  In the end, you will have $D = C A C^T$, So if the signs of the diagonal entries of $D$ are all positive then $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It contributes null to this site.

Comment: @uniquesolution Why do you think that? It is always helpful for everyone to see different aproaches to solve a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). Essentially matrix is positive-definite if and only if all the leading principle minors determinants are positive-definite. We can see
$$|1|>0$$
$$A = \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    2 & 5\\
\end{vmatrix}=1>0$$
$$A = \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    2 & 5 & 4 \\
    3 & 4 & 14 \\
\end{vmatrix}=1>0$$
$$A = \begin{vmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 & -2\\
    2 & 5 & 4 & -5\\
    3 & 4 & 14 & -2 \\
    -2 & -5 & -2 & 10 \\
\end{vmatrix}=1>0$$
Thus by Sylvester's criterion we can conclude that $A$ is positive-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is positive definite because it has a Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^T$ where
$$
L=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\ 2&1&0&0\\ 3&-2&1&0\\ -2&-1&2&1}
$$
is invertible.